# Separate a list into sublists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list that is like this:

```
l = ['a,b,c,d' , 'a,b,c,d', 'a,b,c,d', 'a,b,c,d']
```

and I want to make it so that the list is formatted like this:

```
l = [['a,b,c,d'],['a,b,c,d'],['a,b,c,d'],['a,b,c,d']]
```

or even as four separate lists is fine, but I want to basically be able to iterate through every element in each sublist. This is what I have so far:

```
for string in range(0, len(userlist)):
    small_list = userlist[string:]
    print(small_list)
```

This does not separate the list into the lists that I want however. I'm thinking that I have to break the list off into chunks of 4.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
l = [s.split(",") for s in l]
# result: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to get a list of a list of chars:

```
l = [str.split(",") for str in l]
# prints out [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

or this if you don't want to split your strings into chars:

```
l = [[str] for str in l]
# prints out [['a,b,c,d'], ['a,b,c,d'], ['a,b,c,d'], ['a,b,c,d']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
result = [[each] for each in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda x:[x], l)

output:
[['a,b,c,d'], ['a,b,c,d'], ['a,b,c,d'], ['a,b,c,d']]
```